# Fire projectile at targets coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Aim:**

I'm creating a puck shooter, the shooter spawns a puck every 3 seconds and fires it at a target point within the shooting area of the goal; the shooting area is a plane across the face of the goal which acts as a shooting area as not all shots will be on net - the puck shooter generates a random point within that shooting area which is how it gets the targets X, Y & Z.

I've looked at the different ways of moving an object such as transform.forward, transform.up etc but I think what I'm looking for is puckRB.MovePosition?

As I understand it, with "Is Kinematic" set to true the MovePosition method adds physics to the puck as it's moving across the environment, else it would just teleport it. I'm just not sure how to put the targets coordinates into it with the other stuff it needs?

```
void GetTarget()
{
    float scale = 1f;

    // Grabs the aiming plane
    Transform aimingPlane = GameObject.Find("AimingPlane").gameObject.transform.GetChild(1);

    // Gets the moving X & Y area of the plane
    float moveAreaX = aimingPlane.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x / 2;
    float moveAreaY = aimingPlane.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y / 2;

    // Generates a random value within the move area (X, Y)
    float ranX = Random.Range(-moveAreaX * scale, moveAreaX * scale);
    float ranY = Random.Range(-moveAreaY * scale, moveAreaY * scale);

    // Grabs the center of the AimingPlane
    Vector3 center = aimingPlane.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;

    // Gets the targets coordinates (X and Y)
    targetCoordsX = ranX + center.x;
    targetCoordsY = ranY + center.y;

    // Grabs AimingDot and places at target coordinates
    Transform aimingDot = GameObject.Find("AimingPlane").gameObject.transform.GetChild(0);
    aimingDot.position = new Vector3(targetCoordsX, targetCoordsY, center.z);
}


void FirePuck()
{
    GameObject puckCopy = Instantiate(puck, shotPos.transform.position, shotPos.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

    puckRB = puckCopy.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    Vector3 test = new Vector3(targetCoordsX, targetCoordsY);
    puckRB.MovePosition(test * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

To summarise, so far the program generates a random target within the shooting area, spawns a new puck every 3 seconds, and I'm now just trying to get a puck from the shooter to that target; all the puck currently does is teleports to a point just in front of the shooter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `Rigidbody.MovePosition` does is instantaneously moves the body to the new position (teleports).

Rigidbodies are used for simulating physics on game objects. Enabling `IsKinematic` disables physics for the puck, allowing other objects to detect when they collide with the puck and bounce off of the puck but making the puck unaffected by collisions.

What you want is to have IsKinematic disabled, and set the pucks velocity (speed):

```
puckRB.velocity = (destinationPos - currentPosition).normalized * speed;
```

Subtracting the pucks current position from its destination position gets us the direction vector. `.normalized * speed` will turn that into a unit vector (a vector with a magnitude of 1, and multiply that by the desired travel speed).

```
public float puckSpeed = 1f;

void FirePuck()
{
    GameObject puckCopy = Instantiate(puck, shotPos.transform.position, shotPos.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

    puckRB = puckCopy.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    puckRB.velocity = (new Vector3(targetCoordsX, targetCoordsY, targetCoordsZ) - puckRB.transform.position).normalized * puckSpeed;
}
```